# jquery slider 4 slides at a time issue

Tags: jquery

I've N number of `<li>`'s

I want to make jquery slider to work so that every slide contains 4 `<li>`'s and the rest are hidden in overflow.

I would love to use this plugin: http://slidesjs.com/

My first hunch is to create another jquery plugin that will count li and append div. So that:

```
<div class="slide">
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</div>
<div class="slide">
  <li></li>
</div>
```

But this is dirty, and in any ways incorrect to put div within `<ul>`.

I wonder if this is the only way, and not being a jquery pro I wonder if there are better solutions.

Thanks in advance.

**Chris Kempen**

This looks awesome - so thank you!
I've few problems though:

Your code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    // get the container, useful for later too...
    var container = $("#prefooterslides");

    // get all available UL and LI elements...
    var li_elements = container.find("LI").clone();

    // remove the current content so that we can rebuild it for the slider...
    container.find("UL").remove();

    // build the slider container...
    var slide_container = $("<div />");
    slide_container.addClass("slide");

    // tricky part: looping through the LI's and building each of the slides...
    // first create some helpful variables...
    var li_elements_per_slide = 4;
    var li_counter = 0;
    // create the first slide, with a UL to hold the LI's...
    var current_li_div = $("<div />");
    current_li_div.append($("<ul />"));

    // loop through the LI's...
    li_elements.each(function(index, element){

        li_counter++;
        var current_li = $(element).clone();
        current_li_div.find("UL").append(current_li);

        if (li_counter % li_elements_per_slide == 0)
        {
            // we've hit 4 in this list, so add the slide and make
            // a new one, using same code as before...
            container.append(current_li_div);
            current_li_div = $("<div />");
            current_li_div.append($("<ul />"));
        }

    });

    // we might have an uneven number of LI's, so we need to check for this...
    if (li_counter % li_elements_per_slide != 0)
        container.append(current_li_div);

    // all that's left to do is to initialise the slider script...
    container.slides();

});
</script>
```

My html:

```
<ul id="prefooterslides">

<li>
    <h3><a href="#">SANGIORGIO RESORT</a></h3>
</li>

<li>
    <h3><a href="#">SANGIORGIO RESORT</a></h3>
</li>

<li>
    <h3><a href="#">SANGIORGIO RESORT</a></h3>
</li>

<li>
    <h3><a href="#">SANGIORGIO RESORT</a></h3>
</li>

<!-- end #prefooterslides --></ul>
```

The result:

```
<ul id="prefooterslides">

    <li>
        <h3><a href="#">SANGIORGIO RESORT</a></h3>
    </li>

    <li>
        <h3><a href="#">SANGIORGIO RESORT</a></h3>
    </li>

    <li>
        <h3><a href="#">SANGIORGIO RESORT</a></h3>
    </li>

    <li>
        <h3><a href="#">SANGIORGIO RESORT</a></h3>
    </li>

<div>

    <ul>

        <li>
            <h3><a href="#">SANGIORGIO RESORT</a></h3>
        </li>

        <li>
            <h3><a href="#">SANGIORGIO RESORT</a></h3>
        </li>

        <li>
            <h3><a href="#">SANGIORGIO RESORT</a></h3>
        </li>

        <li>
            <h3><a href="#">SANGIORGIO RESORT</a></h3>
        </li>

    </ul>

</div>
</ul>
```

Things immediately noticeable:

1. container.find("UL").remove(); -> container.find("LI").remove();
2. slide_container.addClass("slide"); this doesn't work.

And while looking at the code I realized there is no need to put everything in div. But using simple `<ul class="slide">` instead is better for correct markup.

Could you please help me resolve this? you've already been too nice writing that jquery for me :)

Comment: Added an edit for you :)

Comment: Thanks! :) you resolved everything for me, I appreciate it.

Comment: Glad everything worked out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your problem then becomes how to split up the N-number of `LI`'s, then initialising the slider with the split-up `LI`'s? Interesting problem, and with some jQuery digging and reconstructing, it's definitely possible.

Starting with an example list of `LI`'s, like this:

```
<div id='main_container'>
    <ul>
        <li>Something something something</li>
        <li>Something something something</li>
        <li>Something something something</li>
        ...
        <li>Something something something</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

...you'd need to obviously grab a list of them, loop through them, and append them back to that main container in the correct format for the slider to pick up on and initialise. I'd be tempted to try something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    // get the container, useful for later too...
    var container = $("#main_container");

    // get all available UL and LI elements...
    var li_elements = container.find("LI").clone();

    // remove the current content so that we can rebuild it for the slider...
    container.find("UL").remove();

    // build the slider container...
    var slide_container = $("<div />");
    slide_container.addClass("slides_container");

    // tricky part: looping through the LI's and building each of the slides...
    // first create some helpful variables...
    var li_elements_per_slide = 4;
    var li_counter = 0;
    // create the first slide, with a UL to hold the LI's...
    var current_li_div = $("<div />");
    current_li_div.append($("<ul />"));

    // loop through the LI's...
    li_elements.each(function(index, element){

        li_counter++;
        var current_li = $(element).clone();
        current_li_div.find("UL").append(current_li);

        if (li_counter % li_elements_per_slide == 0)
        {
            // we've hit 4 in this list, so add the slide and make
            // a new one, using same code as before...
            container.append(current_li_div);
            current_li_div = $("<div />");
            current_li_div.append($("<ul />"));
        }

    });

    // we might have an uneven number of LI's, so we need to check for this...
    if (li_counter % li_elements_per_slide != 0)
        container.append(current_li_div);

    // all that's left to do is to initialise the slider script...
    container.slides();

});
</script>
```

This is assuming you've already included the 'sliders' script. I tried to comment as much as possible and keep it straight-forward, so I hope this helps! But please let me know if you need any clarity! :)

***EDIT #1:***

I've included a [jsfiddle for you here](http://jsfiddle.net/9LHUx/) to have a look at. I've copied / pasted my code and it seems to work ok, but that's based on my initial code with a `div` container.

With my code, you *will* need that `div` container, as the code attempts to follow the [slidejs's example code](http://slidesjs.com/) construction, in which you'll need some kind of container, and some `div`'s to be used as your slides. For that reason, I'd suggest you keep your container for jQuery to feed off, allowing it to correctly put the `li` elements in segregated `div` slide elements following slidejs's code (located [here](http://slidesjs.com/)).

I hope this makes sense! Please let me know if you're still struggling! :)

Comment: Cannot get it to work :( but looks awesome. I'm writing in detail my problems in OP, so that I can use correct highlighting.

Comment: Yes! your right :) putting in container fixed everything. But I still have problems initializing the slider... this should work right: container.slides(); ?

Comment: I'm assuming you've downloaded and included the `slidesjs` script, something like: `<script type="text/javascript" src="/slides.jquery.js"></script>`?

Comment: yep, I already use the same slider for another sliding panel. Could this be a problem? can't I've two sliders with same script on same page? obviously with different handlers and Id's?

Comment: Seems strange that you couldn't have multiple sliders on one page...have you tried duplicating the working slider - just with a different id - and seeing if that works? Also, are there any errors popping up in your console?

Comment: My bad, I was doing it in a wrong way... I had to sepcify container div within container.slides({container: 'divclass'});

million thanks!